# How works AngularJS and Jquery DataTables with delete and edit icons

Tags: jquery, datatables, angularjs

I am studying what's the best client-side javascript framework for use, I am studying AngularJS, BackboneJS and Dojo. My first tests are with AngularJS, in each framework I need to do a TreeView, DataTable and charts.

I did my first test in AngularJS with DataTable, but I need to do a DataTable more full, with more functionalities. But I am finding problems, maybe for understand better the framework.

I have found this link which have a perfect example that I need. But now I have a doubt, about integration between the plugin(DataTables) and o AngularJS.

http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/7kLFU/

This scope array link my Json Data with VIEW(Full code in jsfiddle):

```
    $scope.columnDefs = [ 
        { "bSearchable":false, "mDataProp": "@uri", "aTargets":[0]},
        { "bSearchable":false, "mDataProp": "id", "aTargets":[1]},
        { "bSearchable":true, "mDataProp": "title", "aTargets":[2] },
        { "bSearchable":false, "mDataProp": "count", "aTargets":[3] },
        { "mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<img ng-click='edit()' src='edit.gif' />", "aTargets":[-1] }
    ];
```

I am thinking a little strange to use this way, because if I will put, for example, icons(edit, delete), I will need put, for example, this way:

> 

```
{ "mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<img ng-click='edit()'
> src='edit.gif' />", "aTargets":[-1] }
```

I am mixing HTML. I think there is a better way for to do it. What's the best way to do it?

My other question. In your opinion which one is the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you will have to use `img` with `src` or `span/div` with `class` to show an image in a datatables column

Which is fine INMO.